# Display message on initial login only once without a module

Tags: users

What method is there to show a message on a user that just logged into the site without using a module? I know rules can do it, but I dont want to install a module just to do that. Is there some type of indicator variable that gets set upon initial login?

Answer (score 1):

I propose you to have a look at this: [hook_user_login](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/7), it fires exact on user log-in. A sample code is provided on its documentation page ready to be configured and used.

Answer (score 1):

I just did a preg_match() on the $messages variable in the page.tpl.php file. I had it detect the string "Logged in" which gets displayed when you login.

```
<?php
  print $messages;

  if (preg_match("/Logged in/i", $messages)) {
    print '<div class="messages newfeat">*NEW FEATURE* - My Works Page [X]</div>';
  }
?>
```

Comment: I think you should mark this answer as "accepted", that way it will no longer show up in the [unanswered questions](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/unanswered).